# How to modify jersey response headers

Tags: tomcat, jersey, jetty

I have my rest service running on a Jersey server configured as follow:

```
try {

    final ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath(serverConfig.getContextPath());

    final Server jettyServer = new Server(serverConfig.getPort());
    jettyServer.setHandler(context);

    ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
    config.register(CORSResponseFilter.class);

    final ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, serverConfig.getBaseName());

    jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

    jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "com.myRest.rest");
    jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.classnames", entryPoints());


    jettyServer.start();
    jettyServer.join();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm trying to modify the headers of all responses, so that I use a filter:

```
@Provider
public class CORSResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
        throws IOException {

    MultivaluedMap headers = responseContext.getHeaders();
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Codingpedia");
}
}
```

However, for some reason, this filter is never called.

I'm using embebed jetty 9.2.13.v20150730. I have seen some answers that suggest to change web.xml, but I'm not using xml configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for some reason, this filter is never called

Because you're not doing anything with the `ResourceConfig` that you're registering the filter with. Instead of using the `ServletContainer` class to `addServlet`, you can instantiate it, passing the `ResourceConfig` to the constructor.

```
ServletHolder jerseyServlet = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(config));
jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);
context.addServlet(jerseyServlet, serverConfig.getBaseName());
```

Also instead of using the init parameters, you could just register everything with the `ResourceConfig`. You can set the package scan using the `packages` method, and just register all the providers with the `register` method (instead of using String class names with the init-param).

```
ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig()
    .packages("com.myRest.rest")
    .register(CORSResponseFilter.class)
    .register(AnyOtherProviderClass.class)
    .register(LikeTheOnesYouListedInThe_entryPoints.class)
```